# Unity assets path Android.

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've got a file where I'm saving the highest score. In Unity Editor path is: `path = Application.dataPath + "/Score.json";`
And I don't know how to get path to this file in Android. 
**Error has been deleted**

Comment: You save to use `Application.persistentDataPath` not `Application.dataPath`. You also have to check if the file or directory exist before attempting to save this. Regardless, you are saving game data as json and I think this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Application.dataPath points to .apk file on Android as far as I know. I would suggest you using different paths on each platforms. This is what I prefer to save for saving some game stuff.

```
 public static string Path
        {
            get
            {
                switch (Application.platform)
                {
                    case RuntimePlatform.IPhonePlayer:
                        return Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "MyStuff");

                    case RuntimePlatform.Android:
                        return Path.Combine(Application.temporaryCachePath, "MyStuff");

                    default:
                        return Path.Combine(Directory.GetParent(Application.dataPath).FullName, "MyStuff");
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

On Android, `Application.dataPath` will point to the APK so you should avoid using it for save data since you wont be able to write to it.  Instead, you want to use [`Application.persistentDataPath`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html). As the linked documentation states:

> When publishing on iOS and Android, `persistentDataPath` will point to a
>   public directory on the device. Files in this location won't be erased
>   with each update of the App.

Comment: `#if UNITY_ANDROID
  path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/Score.json";
  Debug.Log("Android device");

#endif` is this right ?

Comment: @Karol Looks good to me.